# How to store X and Y Coordinated of any specific drag n drop div?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, phpmyadmin

I am new to codeigniter and working on E-cards. I am using drag n drop jquery which is working smoothly. I am facing some problem when I am trying to store X and Y coordinates of that drag-able "DIV" into my database. 
Is any solution or helping material to that problem? 
Or how can I get X and Y coordinates and store it to my db?
would be very grateful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look this link-
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

try to add a form and include some hidden inputs there and set it's value to the position of your element and during submission you'll able to get it's value.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this framework

```
 http://www.midorijs.com/midoriDragDrop.html
```

you can register a callback on drop (its given in the end)

in this callback function u can make an ajax call and send the params

Comment: I think I stuck on somewhere. It doesn't send any params.
Can I get ur email Id?